# 4.15.0-48 does not load

Tags: boot

My Ubuntu with kernels 4.15.0-48 and 4.15.0-47 doesn't boot. I see a strip on the screen with a lot of multiple colours. Then Ubuntu shuts down and restarts. the first message is recovering journal but never ends recovering.
Ubuntu 3.13.0.87 starts up.

Comment: Do you mean kernel?

Comment: yes, I mean kernel

Comment: What Ubuntu version may I ask?

Comment: @peter also what is your hardware (graphic card most importantly)

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Comment: Hardware : Packard Bell EasyNoteTJ75 ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5470 Graphics 512 MB

Comment: Status please. Did you perform my fsck answer?

Comment: Yes I did last night. I created a Live DVD and performed your procedure. I had no error. The problem still exist.

Comment: Hi heynnema, do you got my update? Thanks

Comment: @peter Sorry it took so long to get back to you. Start comments to me with "@heynnema" or I'll probably miss them. What make/model computer or motherboard? Edit your question and show me `free -h`. Have you checked that you have the latest BIOS installed? Are you able to get a screenshot of the boot screen, and post it to imgur.com for me?

Comment: @peter to check what version BIOS you have now... `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`.

Comment: @heynnema I did both command, this is the result

Comment: @heynnema zerbini@zerbini-laptop:~$ sudo dmidecode -s bios-version
[sudo] Passwort für zerbini: 
V1.09          
zerbini@zerbini-laptop:~$ free -h
              Gesamt   belegt    frei        gemns. Puffer/Cache verfügbar
Speicher:        3,8G        1,1G        928M         56M        1,8G        2,5G
Auslagerungsspeicher:        8,6G        1,4M        8,6G
zerbini@zerbini-laptop:~$ ^C
zerbini@zerbini-laptop:~$

Comment: @heynnema for the screenshot I need a little bit more time. regrads

Comment: Now take that BIOS version, to the manufacturor's web site, and check if that's the latest version. I'll guess that it's probably not. Download the newest BIOS. Backup your important files. Install the new BIOS. Reboot. Retest booting to the newer kernels. Report back.

Comment: @heynnema, you are right, it's not the newest. the latest is 1.26. I need to go to PB asking how to install. I have a dual boot system the GRUB. one op system is windows 10 and the other one is ubunto. I try to go in touch with the PB support tomorrow to check out how to go forward.

Comment: @peter boot into Windows. Download the updated BIOS. Uncompress it, if need be. Read the installation instructions. Install it. Try and reboot Ubuntu to the newer kernels. Let me know if it works, and I'll update my answer.

Comment: @peter status please

Comment: @heynnema, the BIOS is on actual level now. See following command output:zerbini@zerbini-laptop:~$ sudo dmidecode -s bios-version
[sudo] Passwort für zerbini: 
V1.26          
zerbini@zerbini-laptop:~$ 
but the problem is the same. I couldn't load pictures on imgur.com because I'm not familiar with it. I've problem to handle it. What I've to do with #tags and @mention?

Comment: @peter good job on updating the BIOS! Try booting to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB version 18:10 or 19:04 and lets see if those kernels load for you. The "@" symbol in front of a users name, notifies that user when you leave a comment. Report back.

Comment: @heynnema, I create two USB Liev stick, one with 18.10 and the other one with 19.04. with both I'm able to boot without problems. The only message where pop up at the beginning is: No cache device found / assuming write through the drive. Both system works well.

Comment: @peter Fair enough. Three things... take a picture of that funny colored screen that you describe and upload it to imgur.com for me to see... and describe exactly what you see from power up to when you see this screen... and lastly, edit your question and show me `ls -al /boot`.

Comment: @heynnema, hi please can you give me a short sequence procedure how to upload a picture. I've no experience with imgur, sorry about that. What you mean with "edit your question". When I should execute the command?

Comment: Take a picture with your camera. Upload the picture from your phone to your computer's desktop. Go to imgur.com. Click the "New Post" green button. Upload your picture. Note the URL that's given. Give us that URL so we can go and look at your picture. To edit your question, there's an "Edit" link immediately under your question. That's where you can add complicated details that you can't post in a comment.

Comment: @heynnema, the grub screen come up. Ubuntu is the first entry, I hit the enter key. It's running maybe a minute and then the colored strip appears. After a few seconds later the system switch off. After that it's start again and then I have different symptoms.

Comment: @heynneme there is the URL Screenshot https://imgur.com/gallery/d4GmvL9

Comment: @peter thanks for the screenshot. Lets try something easy first... boot to the GRUB menu, highlight the normal Ubuntu selection, hit the "e" key to enter edit mode, use the arrow keys to find "quiet splash" and change it to "quiet splash nomodeset", then hit control-x or F10 to continue booting, and lets see if it boots fully. Report back.

Comment: @heynneme, I did as you described. The system start. At the end of the start I've my desktop but the size isn't correct (to wide) and I've still the 5 dots of the ubuntu screen. I posted a screenshot. There is the link http://imgur.com/gallery/iTI5ic6

Comment: @heynnema, I could startup with a new kernel (after update).I got the same coloured strip but the system doesn't shut down. I switch off/on an the system started up. I performed following command "journalctl -b". the are some red messages. I extracted this messages an edited it. Sorry for writing your user id wrong.

Comment: @peter Good. Progress! You didn't show me the journalctl error messages. You can copy/paste them at paste.ubuntu.com. What video card and driver do you have?

Comment: @heynnema, sorry for the long delay. I couldn't reproduce the error message. I paste following information under poster pzerbini at paste.ubuntu.com. it's output of lshw -c video and modinfo radeon. I see only a version of 00. I started up normally with ubunto, 2/3 of the screen with coloured pixel, the system switch of, I restart. ubuntu comes up normaly.

Comment: @peter I can't find your paste.ubuntu.com by your user pzerbini. I need the URL. Try again if need be. Do you know what the make/model of your card, and the version of AMD/Nvidia? driver?

Comment: @heynnema, there is the url of https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Sd5HsPqn56/ (Paste from pzerbini at Thu, 9 May 2019 16:24:48 +0000). I don't no what the make/model of my card is and the version of AMD/Nvidia (what is AMD Nvidia?)

Comment: @peter thanks for the updated info. Since booting to a Ubuntu Live USB for 18.10/19.04 seems to work... and you know what I'm about to say, yes :-) ... go ahead and upgrade your Ubuntu. Lets see if that solves the problem. Report back.

Comment: @heynnema I started to update from 18.04 to 18.10 by the Software & Update function. He ended up at first step with the message "apt architecture is i386" "Upgrades from 18.04 on the i386 architecture are not supported at this time". How I can upgrade without installing 18.10 completely new.

Comment: @peter please see Update #2 in my answer.

Comment: @peter Please remember to accept my answer if it was helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Lets first check your file system for errors.

For 18.04 or newer...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- open a `terminal` window
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/XXXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/XXXX` # replacing XXXX with the number you found earlier
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

**Update #1:**

Recommend to update BIOS from 1.09 to the latest 1.26. Then retry booting to the newer kernels.

**Update #2:**

Turns out that the user has a 64-bit computer (as Ubuntu Live 18.10/19.04 DVD/USB boots fine), that has an i386 version of Ubuntu 18.04 installed. There is no direct upgrade path from i386 version to 18.10/19.04. You need to backup your important data, install a **fresh** copy of 18.10/19.04, and then restore your data.